# Joining elements together in a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

The input:

```
z = ", "
y = " "
chands = {'theboard': [('Diamonds', 'Four'), ('Clubs', 'Three'), ('Clubs', 'King'), ('Clubs', 'Two'), ('Hearts', 'Jack')]}
```

My expected output:

```
'Diamonds Four, Clubs Three, Clubs King, Clubs Two, Hearts Jack'
```

I've tried:

```
print chands["theboard"][0][0]+y+chands["theboard"][0][1]+z+chands["theboard"][1][0]+y+chands["theboard"][1][1]+z+chands["theboard"][2][0]+y+chands["theboard"][2][1]
```

Is there a better way to print this?

Comment: What is `y` and `z`?

Comment: z = ", "
y = " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `map` + `str.join`, once on `y` and once more on `z` -

```
>>> z.join(map(y.join, chands['theboard']))
'Diamonds Four, Clubs Three, Clubs King, Clubs Two, Hearts Jack'
```

If you want to join just the first 3 tuples, you can index `chands` and slice the result -

```
>>> z.join(map(y.join, chands['theboard'][:3]))
'Diamonds Four, Clubs Three, Clubs King'
```

---

Another way to do this with a list comprehension would be -

```
>>> z.join([y.join(x) for x in chands['theboard'][:3]])
'Diamonds Four, Clubs Three, Clubs King'
```

Comment: thank you, additionally how do i print 3 out of 5 of the tuples in chands